# ST_COVEREDBY passes using geometry but fails with geography

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, geography

I have a table of points and a table of polygons in PostgreSQL 11.18 and PostGIS 2.4.4. Both use Geography SRS 4326.

```
CREATE TABLE my_points (
  id integer generated by default as identity,
  geom geography(Point, 4326) not null
);

CREATE TABLE my_polygons (
  id integer generated by default as identity,
  geom geography(Polygon, 4326) not null
);
```

I have a point that is inside a polygon, but **very close to the boundary**. When I query whether the point is inside the polygon using geography the result is negative:

```
SELECT ST_COVEREDBY(points.geom, polygon.geom) as result
FROM points, polygons
WHERE points.id = 1 AND polygons.id = 1;
```

produces:

```
result
----
False
```

But when I cast to geometries the result is different!

```
SELECT ST_COVEREDBY(points.geom::geometry, polygon.geom::geometry) as result
FROM points, polygons
WHERE points.id = 1 AND polygons.id = 1;
```

produces:

```
result
----
True
```

What is the explanation for this?

(I can provide the specific data upon request.)

Comment: Line segments in `geography` features take great ellipse routes, not the Cartesian segments used by `geometry`. The specific data would be necessary to prove it in your case.

Comment: BTW: While PostgreSQL 11.x is currently supported, its end-of-life is only two months away. Even in a risk-adverse environment, you ought to be at PG13 or PG14 by now.

Comment: See the image in this answer  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163817/postgis-intersection-between-geometry-and-geography.

Comment: Thanks @Vince. But I still don't understand why the following returns false. The line along the surface of the earth for the following polygon should run directly along 44 degrees latitude, even though its a sphere.

    select st_coveredby(st_makepoint(-115, 44.00000001)::geography, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-110 44, -120 44, -120 45, -110 45, -110 44))')::geography)

Comment: No, the great circle route between two points on +44 latitude tips a bit north of 44N. Take a string and pull it taut between two pushpins on a globe, and you'll see this is true.

Comment: I did as you suggested and you are right! I have 32 years experience with GIS, including a PhD and I just had my world rocked (literally). Thank you @Vince